# Learning Python Splits and Joins?

Tags: python, join, python-2.7, split, list-comprehension

I thought I was understanding splits and joins in python but it is not working right for me.

lets say the value of `inp[17] = 'Potters Portland Oregon school of magic'`

```
# a string of data I am pulling from a csv file, the data comes through just fine.
loc = inp[17] 

l = loc.split(' ') # I want to split by the space

# I want to filter out all these words say they don't always 
# come as "School of magic" so I cant just filter that out they 
# could be mixed around at times.

locfilter = ['Potters', 'School', 'of', 'magic']     
locname = ' '.join([value for value in l if l not in locfilter])
```

At this point my `locname` variable should only have `Portland Oregon` in it, but it still has `'Potters Portland Oregon school of magic'` it didn't filter out.

What have I done wrong I think the problem is in my `locname =` line.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here isn't your `split` or `join`, it's just a silly mistake in the condition in your list comprehension (the kind of silly mistake all of us make all the time):

```
locname = ' '.join([value for value in l if l not in locfilter])
```

Obviously `l` is never in `locfilter`. And if you fix that:

```
locname = ' '.join([value for value in l if value not in locfilter])
```

It works fine:

```
'Portland Oregon school'
```

Note that `'school'` is still part of the output. That's because `'school'` wasn't in `locfilter`; `'School'` was. If you want to match these case-insensitively:

```
lowerfilter = [value.lower() for value in locfilter]
locname = ' '.join([value for value in l if value.lower() not in lowerfilter])
```

And now:

```
'Portland Oregon'
```

Comment: +1 Although the capitalization of *school* could still be a problem.

Comment: @kojiro: Yeah, I was in the middle of explaining that…

Comment: Thanks a ton that makes sense I really appreciate the explanation everything works as expected now.

Comment: Note that using `.lower()` like this really only works for western-Latin-script languages. If you were using Python 3, I'd recommend `casefold()` instead. But in 2.x, the only "right" ways to handle this are more complicated, so… if you only care about English, just stick to `lower` until you're ready for Python 3.